# ftp_get giving error while fetching a file

Tags: php, ftp

Im trying to fetch a csv file from a remote server with ftp_get

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$okk=0;
// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))  (line 31)
{
        $okk=1;
}
```

but its giving following error

> Warning: ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection for /abc/abc.csv(198528 bytes). in /home/a/b/c/cm_data/d.php on line 31

I tried changing it to ascii mode then too it gave error

> Warning: ftp_get(): Opening ASCII mode data connection for /abc/abc.csv(198528 bytes). in /home/a/b/c/cm_data/d.php on line 31

i also tried using `ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);` too but still gives error.

What is the problem please help!!

Comment: I thing it could be problems with file location on server or file permissions. Try to set file permissions to 777.

Comment: theres no permission error here.

Answer (score 4):

ftp_pasv needs to be called *after* ftp_login!

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to treat error cases from `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login`.

Please try the following code and see if it gives some errors:

```
<?php

    $ftp_server = $ftp_server;
    $ftp_user = $ftp_user_name;
    $ftp_pass = $ftp_user_pass;

    // set up a connection or die
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

    // try to login
    if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
        echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            $okk=1;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
    }

    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);  

?>
```

Comment: I edited the code because I copied (line 31) also - I hope you did not tried with that there :D. Until line 31 you don't get any message at all - meaning that ftp_connect and ftp_login were both successful?

Comment: Does the php have write permission to the $local_file? does the $server_file exists? try to write $local_file into /tmp/ - this should be writable by anyone